Proof that countable product on simplicies it sequentially compactness
Let $\Delta_n$ denote the $n$-dimensional simplex. I want to show that the product of countably many $n$-dimensional simplicies $(\Delta_n)^\mathbb{N}$ is sequentially compact. That is, given a sequence $(d_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $d_i\in(\Delta_n)^\mathbb{N}$, is there a subsequence $(d_{j_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ (where $j_n$ is strictly increasing) which converges, i.e. $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}d_{j_n}\in (\Delta_n)^\mathbb{N}$.
I think I can prove this: $\Delta_n$ is compact. By Tychonoff's theorem $(\Delta_n)^\mathbb{N}$ is compact. Also it is metrizable (take e.g. the $L^{\infty}$ distance), hence compactness and sequential compactness coincide.
Alternatively, $\Delta_n$ is also sequentially compact (again since it's compact and metrizable), and a Countable Product of Sequentially Compact spaces is Sequentially Compact

Now where I am not sure about both of these proofs is that both use the product topology and do not work in general for the box topology. I am not that familiar with topology, so I am not sure how this impacts my application. In particular I dont't see how the property I want to prove (sequential compactness) is affected by whether I use the box or product topology. I would appreciate any insight into whether there are any implicit restrictions that I made, e.g. about $(\Delta_n)^\mathbb{N}$ and how that impacts the possible $d_i$.

Box topology and product topology are different (how the bases of them are defined) when the product is made of an infinitude number of sets. Therefore using Tychonoff's theorem for ${(\Delta_{n})}^{\mathbb{N}}$ to show that it is compact is invalid as the topology on ${(\Delta_{n})}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is the box topology and there is an infinite number of sets.

I do not understand why the box topology should be the topology on $(\Delta_n)^\mathbb{N}$. Can't I just choose to equip it with the product topology? Then my question would be whether there are any consequences on choosing the product topology that invalidate my proof (and if yes, which).

I'm sorry. I didn't see which topology is defined on ${(\Delta_{n})}^{\mathbb{N}}$. If it is the product topology then your proof is fine. Otherwise, the proof is invalid as I pointed out in the previous comment. The point is that you need to look into the text that contains this problem (if you got this from a text) to know which topology is defined on it. Compactness is a property of topological spaces, and a topological space is a set with a collection of subsets that satisfies certain axioms, so you cannot just choose a topology to show that a space is compact.

Why do you think that the product should be given the box topology? Is there any hint in the source of your problem?
